# Mongoose array of object in a schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to nodejs and facing issue with creating a document that contains an array of object I have defined schema as below

```
var field2Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fField1: String,
    fField2: String,
    fField3: String
}, { _id: false});

 var schemaName = new mongoose.Schema({
    field1: String,
    field2: [field2Schmea]
}, { collection: testSchema});
```

I want to push an array of objects in field2 before saving the record. I have tried many ways but I am unable to push any value. Is there a way to push the values into this before inserting the record in mongo using .save() on mongoose to save record

Edit:
I have tried iterating through the array which contains data and the code is below

```
var arrayContainingData = [];

 arrayContainingData .push({
     fField1: "Test"
     fField2: "Test",
     fField3: "Test"});

 var schema = schemaModelClass.schema(mongoose, collectionName); 
 schema.field1 = field1;
 var arrayObject = new rulesModel.field2();

for (var i = 0; i < arrayContainingData.length; i++) {
    
    arrayObject.fField1 = arrayContainingData[i].fField1;
    arrayObject.fField2 = arrayContainingData[i].fField2;
    arrayObject.fField3 = arrayContainingData[i].fField3;
    
    schema.field2.push(arrayObject);
}
```

After this calling

```
schema.save();
```

The problem I am facing is that
schema.field2.push(arrayObject);
doesnot update and no values from arrayObjects are reflected in field2 it's empty.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, what is the expected results, and what goes wrong.

Comment: This isn't really helpful, as too many details are missing. What is the `ruleModel.field2() function? where is `arrayContainingData` defined and what does it hold? please edit your question with a [mre]

Comment: @ISAE updated with more information